# files are not getting added in jump list, say, in notepad+

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, jumplist

in w8-32 bit, as well as in w10-64 bit, new files that I open and use and save in some software are not automatically getting added to jump.

I am observing this in notepad+

If jump list is a feature provided by windows, it should automatically work on all software whose icon I have pinned on taskbar.

or do I need to ask this question on notepad+ forum as there intervention is required?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the closest solution was the notepad++ plugin NppJumpList which only supported up to Windows 7.

Comment: I had already installed NppJumpList, but it is not adding things properly.

Comment: NppJumpList only works with Windows 7 and below. As far as I know there is no solution to your problem. Unless you write one or update NppJumpList.